# Drupal Paths destination

Tags: drupal, path

How can I change destination paths in Drupal? For example, instead of having http://localhost/cuba/user?destination=node/25/add-review, I want http://localhost/gameswapuk/user?destination=content/(name of the node)/add-review.

What I mean is replacing node/25 for the name or title of the node automatically.

Comment: Have you treid checking Configuration > Search and metadata > URL aliases > Patterns ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi use [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.
Module automatically generates URL/path aliases for various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without requiring the user to manually specify the path alias.